# Loop and sum if condition matched

Tags: excel, vba

A simple question: I want to sum up `col A, col B and col C` value `if col D match the value = "OK"`, whether the result is 0 or not, for example,
the result for sum up col A is 17, col B is 0 and col C is 47, how can I do that?

```
A   B   C   D
10  0   20  OK
20  25  30  NOT READY
5   0   15  OK
5   5   10  NOT READY
2   0   12  OK
```

Answer (score 2):

You've specified a VBA solution but I would recommend reverting to an `Application.WorksheetFunction` using the [SUMIF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b)

```
dim dSumA as double
dSumA = application.sumif(columns("D"), "OK", columns("A"))
```

That will get you the total for column A, Columns B & C should be pretty easy from there.